# How to add UIActivityIndicatorView to the bottom of UITableView, and toggle it on loadings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a "scroll to load more" behavior on my `UITableView`. It starts loading more content when you scroll to the bottom. What I want to achieve is to show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` at the bottom of the UITableView when service call is in progress, and hide it when new items are added.

What is a good way to solve this problem? I am using Swift but objective-C solutions are also welcome.

[image: Footer loading]

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same functionality in objective-C

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (indexPath.row == [self.yourArrayData count] - 1)
{
     // Call the API
     [self loadMoreData:@"all" andPages:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)pages] AndIsLoadMore:YES];
}
```

Add loader or design

```
-(void)addLoaderViewAtBottom {
    viewLoader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-100, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [viewLoader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:viewLoader];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator1 = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator1.center = CGPointMake((SCREEN_SIZE.width/2), 30);
    activityIndicator1.alpha = 1.0;
    activityIndicator1.hidden = NO;
    [viewLoader addSubview:activityIndicator1];

    [activityIndicator1 startAnimating];

}

-(void)hideLoaderView {
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [viewLoader setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

                 }];
}
```

then use this two methods in your API call method. Call `addLoaderViewAtBottom` when API call starts and call `hideLoaderView` after getting the responses

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `UIActivityIndicatorView`:

```
@interface MyBulletinVC ()
{
   UIActivityIndicatorView *activityLoadMore;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
   activityLoadMore = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray)];
}
```

Check when `UITableView` is being scrolled and what is the `content offset`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
   float tblBottomEdge = _tblBulletin.frame.size.height+_tblBulletin.frame.origin.y;

   if (bottomEdge <= tblBottomEdge)
   {
      return;
   }

   if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
   {
      [self show_bottom_loader];
   }
}
```

If applicable as per `content offset` then display loader in footer of table:

```
-(void)show_bottom_loader
{
  _tblBulletin.tableFooterView = [self returnLoaderViewWhileFetchingRecords];
  CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, [_tblBulletin contentSize].height -  _tblBulletin.bounds.size.height);
  [_tblBulletin setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:YES];
  [self getNewsRecords];
}
```

Hide footer when data is loaded:

```
-(void)hide_bottom_loader
{
 _tblBulletin.tableFooterView = nil;
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [_tblBulletin setTableFooterView:v];
 [activityLoadMore stopAnimating];
}

-(UIView*)returnLoaderViewWhileFetchingRecords
{
  UIView *view  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,_tblBulletin.frame.size.width,44)];
  view.backgroundColor  =[UIColor clearColor];

  UILabel *lblBg =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,1,_tblBulletin.frame.size.width,42)];
  lblBg.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];
  [view addSubview:lblBg];

  UILabel *lbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_tblBulletin.frame.size.width/2 - 20,0,_tblBulletin.frame.size.width/2,view.frame.size.height)];
  lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  lbl.text = @"Loading...";
  lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f];
  lbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
  lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  lbl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  [view lbl];

  activityLoadMore.frame = CGRectMake(_tblBulletin.frame.size.width/2-35,22,0,0);
  [activityLoadMore startAnimating];
  [view addSubview:activityLoadMore];

  return view;
}

-(void)getNewsRecords  
{
    //fetch new records and add to your array.  
    [self hide_bottom_loader];  
    //reload table.
}
```

Replace `tblBulletin` with you table name.